# APDU App that sends an ID# to my NFC shield in target mode

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, apdu

I am trying to use my phone as an ID. I want to send about an 8 digit # using APDU. I have an arduino NFC shield that I have programmed to be in "target" mode (refernce b), so it is just waiting for the "initiator" to send the data. I am basing my project off of these two projects.

a)http://sdiwc.net/digital-library/web-admin/upload-pdf/00000426.pdf
b)http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/NFC_Shield_V2.0

I have also been searching for a raw app that maybe I can add onto, but has the isodep already included in it. I am very new to all of these topics. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.